# TeX4HT \textregistered and an unwanted semicolon

Tags: fonts, symbols, tex4ht, superscripts, html

Using `\textregistered{}` and/or `\textregistered` result in `®; ®;`

Is there a way I can redefine this symbol so that it doesn't include a semicolon or is there a package conflict that is causing this problem?

I had to redefine `\textrademark` in an if statement because it wasn't working `\renewcommand{\texttrademark}{{\si{^{TM}}}}` so I am concerned of a compatibility problem somewhere.  Not quite sure what the offending package is however since the way I understand it, numerous packages redefine and avail a user of font and symbol controls.

Comment: An example of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in `tex4ht`, `\textregistered` is defined like this in `html4.4ht`:

```
\def\:tempc{\special{t4ht@+\string&{35}xAE{59}}x;}
\HLet\textregistered\:tempc
```

this may seem little bit cryptic, but `\special{t4ht@+\string&{35}xAE{59}}` outputs special instruction to replace letter `x` with html entity `&#xAE;`, this html entity is in later process translated to `®` character. there is unnecessary `;` character. to fix this, put this into the preamble:

```
\renewcommand\textregistered{\special{t4ht@+\string&{35}xAE{59}}x}
```

I posted a [bug report](http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?242) with a patch to `tex4ht` bug db, so I hope it will be fixed quickly in TeXLive:

Comment: Interestingly I can't seem to overwrite \textregistered.  I am sure the code you posted should work, but even using \renewcommand{\textregistered}{^{\si{R}}} (which is similar to how I fixed TM doesn't change anything.

Comment: @EngBIRD maybe you use some package which redefines \textregistered? try to put that definition after begin{document}`

Comment: Great thanks!  I usually put these sort of new commands in a tex document called immediately before the \begin{document}  Turns out that wasn't enough.  As per your suggestion, placing it inside \begin{document} fixed it right up.