# Modular LaTeX document preambles and class files

Tags: packages, document-classes, preamble, document-configuration

I have been debating whether or not to ask this question as I don't intend to create an overly broad unanswerable, or solely opinion based question, but I have decided that there are probably some  techniques that will adequately answer this question.

I am looking for approaches I can use to organize my code to simplify or clean up my class file or document preamble.  Below is some example snippets and organization from my cls file.  I have tried to keep as much of this customization and configuration in the cls file rather than in a complex document preamble as I want the cls file to be a template that requrires minimal customizations in constantly changing main files that would contain a preamble.

Because it's all in my cls file (which I fear is on its way to an unmanageable length).  When I branch off to a new project I would like to be able start from the same class file, and just prune out and modify what is relevant.  One of the primary motivations is to prevent duplication when some global concepts always need to be updated, while other customizations definitely need to be stand alone.  Since `\input{}` seems to very nicely let me use `../..` to navigate to where I would prefer to store individual config files (except across drives)

One of the few aspects of my document preamble is the configuration of newcommands, renewcommands, and files loaded and configured for glossaries which are all loaded in distinct files

```
\input{../src/private/my-newcommands}
\input{../src/private/config-glossary}  % Glossaries must be loaded before amsmath
```

so using this concept can the cls file be modularized and compartmentalized?

I had created some (what I had been describing as) `config files` that contained specific package loads and modifications for common tasks such as math, fonts, header/footer, titles, bibliography, formatting modifications, etc.  But transporting some variable definitions, commands, environments, and packages (such as hyperref, cleveref, amsmath, etc) don’t seem to work when sorted into discrete tex files that are called using `input` or `include` is inside the cls file.

I can't provide a MWE for this as it seems irreproducible depending on what I put in these external tex files.  For example, the color definitions and includes worked fine when grabbed with `\input{}`  Should these by sty files instead for this to be possible?

Because a tex installation on linux has different rules about where a cls or sty file can be placed to be read, I will detail that this question is being asked with MikTex on windows in mind, but I am certainly open to comments about parallel organization structures on linux.  For interests sake, one of the reasons that my cls file gets so complicated is my documents must be compatible with both `xelatex` and `tex4ht`.

Organizational example - I can't guarantee that any of this will run as I have not pruned this file with this intention, just tried to include some examples of content that I keep in my cls file:

```
    %_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
    %
    % C L A S S   F I L E   S E T T I N G S    
    %_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
    \ProvidesClass{EngBird_Template}[2013/10/01 

    %http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24542/create-list-of-all-external-files-used-by-master-latex-document
    %\RequirePackage{snapshot}


    \LoadClass[12pt, twoside, letterpaper]{report}  %oneside

    %\RequirePackage{standalone}
    \RequirePackage{letltxmacro}
    %\RequirePackage{Sweave}
%
%_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

% TODO List
% Try an organize in small modular components
% Fix bolds in section hierarchy titles   
%==========================================================================================================================================
% PACKAGES REQUIRED FOR CONFIGURING REPORT  - PAGE MARGINS AND LINE SPACING
%==========================================================================================================================================
%
    \RequirePackage[letterpaper,includehead,
        left=3.25cm,right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,
        headheight=1.5cm,headheight=0.0cm,
        bottom=2.54cm,footskip=1.0cm
        %hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3.75cm %only used to get rid of a overfull \hbox warning.
        ]{geometry}

    \RequirePackage{parskip}
    \RequirePackage{setspace}

    % CONFIGURE PAGE SPACING AND HYPHEN RESTRICTION CRITERION   
    \pagestyle{plain} % options: empty , plain , fancy
    \onehalfspacing
    \righthyphenmin=6
    \lefthyphenmin=6

    %http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11707/how-to-force-output-to-a-left-or-right-page
    %\cleardoublepage
    \RequirePackage{emptypage}  %http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21629/avoiding-page-numbers-in-empty-pages
        \newcommand*{\cleartoleftpage}{%
          \clearpage
            \if@twoside
            \ifodd\c@page
              \hbox{}\newpage
              \if@twocolumn
                \hbox{}\newpage
              \fi
            \fi
          \fi
        }
%
%_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________


%=========================================================================================================================================
% PACKAGES REQUIRED CREATING CUSTOM COLORS
%=========================================================================================================================================

    \ifdefined\HCode
    %   \RequirePackage[html]{tex4ht}
        \RequirePackage[dvips]{xcolor}
    \else
        \RequirePackage{xcolor}%color %\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
    \fi


    \definecolor{Crimson}{rgb}{0.6471, 0.1098, 0.1882}
    \definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
    \definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55} % chapter numbers will be semi transparent .5 .55 .6 .0
    \definecolor{webgreen}{rgb}{0,.5,0}
    \definecolor{webbrown}{rgb}{.6,0,0}
    \definecolor{Maroon}{cmyk}{0, 0.87, 0.68, 0.32}
    \definecolor{RoyalBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.50, 0, 0}
    \definecolor{Black}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0}
%_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
%=========================================================================================================================================
%   SNIPPETS FROM http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/ TO IMPROVE FORMATTING AND APPEARENCE  
%   See also ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/documentation/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf
%   http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73421/how-to-create-specific-chapter-style-in-book-documentclass
%=========================================================================================================================================

%http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex  \hfill \kern \z@}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    %\vspace*{50\p@}%
    %\vspace*{6\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \singlespacing
        \thickhrulefill\quad
        \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \quad \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{6\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{6\p@}%
        %\fontsize{19}{6}
        \Large 
        \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{6\p@}%
        \hrule
        \vskip 20\p@
        %\vskip 100\p@
    }}

    \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
        %\vspace*{50\p@}%
        % \vspace*{6\p@}%
        {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
            \singlespacing
            \thickhrulefill
            \par\nobreak
            \vspace*{6\p@}%
            \interlinepenalty\@M
            \hrule
            \vspace*{6\p@}%
            %\fontsize{19}{6}
            \Large 
            \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
            \par
            \vspace*{6\p@}%
            \hrule
            \vskip 20\p@
            %\vskip 100\p@
        }}

% some definitions
\def\year#1{\gdef\@year{#1}}                    % specified in coverpage.tex
\def\month#1{\gdef\@month{#1}}              % specified in coverpage.tex

\newcommand{\maketitlepage}
{ 
    \singlespacing
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill} \vspace{2cm} \begin{center}
        \Huge \textcolor{Crimson}{\textit{\MyTitle}} \normalsize \\ \sc \vspace{2cm}
        \vspace*{1.0cm}
        \normalsize
        by \\
        \vspace*{1.0cm}
        \large {\textit{\@author}} \normalsize \\ \sc \vspace{1cm}

        \normalsize \vspace*{2.0cm}

        etc \\

    \end{center} \vspace*{\fill}
}
%=========================================================================================================================================

%=========================================================================================================================================
% Special einvironment modifications
%=========================================================================================================================================

%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17887/prevent-abstract-environment-to-reset-pagenumbering
% either use notitlepage in the \LoadClass or this
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \if@twocolumn
    \section*{\abstractname}%
  \else
    %\small
    \begin{center}%
      {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation
  \fi}
  {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}

%_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________


%=========================================================================================================================================
%  E Q U A T I O N  C A P T I O N  S E T U P 
%=========================================================================================================================================

\DeclareCaptionType{mycapequ}[][List of equations]
\captionsetup[mycapequ]{labelformat=empty}
```

This class file is loaded in by the main latex document setup as follows:

```
%=============================================================================
%   P R E A M B L E
%=============================================================================
%______________________________________________________________________________________
%
% Setup the document class and enable a package to read preamble and files externally    %______________________________________________________________________________________
\documentclass{EngBird_Template}  

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Create a listing in the log of all files needed to process this document
\listfiles
\synctex=1 % turn synctex on automatically to sync between pdf viewer
%\setupbackend[export=yes]  % should be using with ConTeXt 
%\setupbackend     [export=example.xml, css=example.css]
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\input{../src/private/my-newcommands} 
\input{../src/private/config-glossary}  % Glossaries must be loaded before amsmath

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}   %\nocite{*}       % list all refs in database, cited or not

\begin{document}
    \ifdefined\HCode    \renewcommand{\textregistered}{\special{t4ht@+\string&{35}xAE{59}}x}    \else   \fi
    \input{../src/logical_contents}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

I think it might be worth mentioning that the modular spirit of this question could be applied to extend to workarounds for the `texmf` directory structure in an age of network computing.  People like me use numerous computers and collaborate with others and as such absolute path names don't always work out great, and relative paths can be equally problematic.  As a `LaTeX` user and enthusiast, but certainly not a developer, I find that my own code for customizations (in class and sty files) are not easily made portable, but also accessible to multiple projects, on multiple platforms, for multiple users.

Comment: Using `\input` should work. Don't use `\include` in a `.cls` file. What doesn't work with `\input`?

Comment: Related: [Classes and packages – what's the difference?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21909) -- from that, I'd say anything that's not specific to a particular type of document (thesis, tech report, etc.) should be in a package. For me, `\include` is only for chapters. If I have my packages in version control, I can check them out into my [TEXMFHOME](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/installsty.html) folder on any platform (e.g., C:/users/me/texmf on Windows, /home/me/texmf on Linux). No idea what to tell you about `xelatex` and `tex4ht`.

Comment: @cfr the first time I noticed my document stopped working when I compartmentalized it was with an initilization of `def`
`\newcommand{\maketitlepage}`.  The variable assignment and object creation are in their own tex file (and this document is called with input within begin{document}, but when I put the definition in it's own file it stopped working.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Sorry about the ambiguity, xelatex and tex4ht are not causing any problems so maybe I shouldn't have mentioned this, its just that having to configure with an \ifdefined\HCode and multiple instances of the same packages or package alternatives depending on the compile system really bloats the file, and would be far more manageable if I could have a more modular structure.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about calling it 'within `\begin{document}`'. Do you `\input` the file in the preamble or in the document? Not that it should matter. More precisely, it should make no difference provided you input it at the point you'd otherwise include the commands.

Comment: @cfr as per a previous question I opened (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223804/tex4ht-textregistered-and-an-unwanted-semicolon) I have a renewcommand that will only work when placed immediately within `\begin{document}`

Comment: @EngBIRD It would be helpful if you gave at least a schematic example here. I guess for this particular point, you mean 'immediately ***after*** `\begin{document}`'? Or are you using e.g. `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand...}` or similar? It is very difficult to figure out from your question what you are doing. We don't have any example code which causes the problem and we don't have much idea of how you are including it or where. You haven't confirmed that you are not using `\include` in a `.cls` file, for example, so we can't even rule that out.

Comment: @cfr I have updated my question to include some examples from my cls file, and my main tex file.  The main file at the bottom of the question will illustrate what I  mean by 'immediately after \begin{document}.  Apologies in my comment to mico's answer below I mentioned I exclusively use requirepackage; I never use usepackage, include, or even input at this time.

Comment: Whatever else you do, don't load the `pdfsync` package. For one, it's not needed if you use a version of pdfLaTeX/XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX that's more recent than ca 2008. And, as the package's user guide warns prominently, "pdfsync uses extremely sensible code. You should not use `pdfsync` on final documents because it can change the layout rather significantly (different page/line breaks are the most obvious changes) ..."

Comment: @Mico Thanks! Permanently removed.  Definitely want to remove potentially conflicting packages.  It was almost always commented out because I could never tell if it was doing anything, but since it is dangerous to include I appreciate the advice to keep the document stable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understood the setup of your class file, the ways you load various packages, and the ways new macros are defined (or existing ones are redefined). For sure, don't load packages -- typically in files with extension .sty -- via an `\input` statement. Instead, use `\usepackage` directives. If for no other reason, you should do so because `\usepackage` offers some protection against loading the same package twice (or more frequently...) with incompatible options. Similarly, you may want to rename the files you currently load via `\input` statements to have extension `.sty`, so that they can (should?) be loaded via `\usepackage` statements.

Separately, have you implemented document class-level options which let you decide at run time which packages should, or should not, be loaded?

Comment: I can't say that I understood everything in your answer here but I am sure I will learn a lot clarifying a few of these aspects.  My cls file currently uses only `\RequirePackage{}` calls to load packages.  I have no sty files local to my project and currently, only a small collection `siunitx` newcommands, latin abbreviations newcommands, and glossaries setup are in the document preamble using `\input{}` and I have no qualms with any of these approaches in terms of functionality except for their ability to be 'outsourced'.  I don`t understand the document class-level options statement.

Comment: I updated my question to include some examples of syntax used to setup my cls file.  I hope this can help clarify the way I load packages and define macros.